# I am creating array of sprites and they should appare randomly but its happening?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am trying to create array sprites which contain 5 sprites as `0.png`, `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, `4.png`.

I want them to appear randomly on the screen.

Below is my code but its not working, any help?

```
   std::vector <CCSprite*> _sprites;
   _sprites.reserve(10); 

    int spritearray[5] = { 0.png,1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png }; // I AM GETTING ERROR HERE?
     int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        CCSprite* foo = new cocos2d::CCSprite();
       int index = rand() % 5;
       // foo->initWithFile(index);
        foo->setPosition(ccp(60,50*i));
        _sprites.push_back(foo); //store our sprites to do other stuffs later
        this->addChild(foo,1);
    }
```

Comment: `0.png` is not an `int`. Are you maybe supposed to have an array of strings?

Comment: "not working" is not a good description of a problem - what do you get and what do you expect to happen and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to store array of sprites and i want them to appear on the screen randomly please let me know the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "logic" currently is fine, it's the implementation that you have problem with.

If you check the [`initWithFile`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/d8/de9/group__sprite__nodes.html#gacb7bd480bcf1904eebefd2c6063607ba) function, you see that it takes a *file name* as a *string*.

So you need to make an array of strings (the file names) and not an array of integers. Then you use the random index as index into this file-name array and pass it as argument to the `initWithFile` function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are using the same code I provided you before:

```
 std::vector <CCSprite*> _sprites;
_sprites.reserve(10); 

std::vector<std::string> _spriteNames = {"0.png", "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"};

for (int i=0;i < _spriteNames.size(); i++)
{
   CCSprite* foo = cocos2d::CCSprite::create(_spriteNames.at(i));

    int random = rand() % 5;

    foo->setPosition(CCPoint((60 * random), (50 * random)));

    _sprites.push_back(foo); // <- store your sprites to do stuff to them later.

   addChild(foo, 1); //<-- this is adding the child.
}
```